# CSS Divs positioning

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm trying to better understand CSS. Can someone help me out with this. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="DivParent">
<div class="Div1"></div>
<div class="Div2"></div>
</div>
```

I need to position them as shown on this diagram:
http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/divs_diagram.png

I wrote the following CSS:

```
.DivParent
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.Div1
{
    border: 4px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
.Div2
{
    border: 4px solid #00FF00;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Div1 should first stretch horizontally to the right. Div2 should not stretch at all. It can be pushed to the right by Div1 until there's no more room for Div2 to go to the right. After that the Div1 should start growing down (or vertically).

The above works if both Divs are not wide enough, but then Div2 simply gets pushed underneath Div1. How do I keep Div2 always to the right off Div1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this

1. give the `parent div` a fixed `width`.  Use `overflow:hidden;` to contain the `divs`
2. change the `floats` on the inside `divs` to `display:inline-block;`
3. set `width` on a the right `div`
4. set a `max-width` on the left `div`

   ```
   .DivParent{
       border: 1px solid #000000;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       overflow:hidden;
       width:550px;
   }

   .Div1{
       border: 4px solid #FF0000;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
       max-width:400px;
       display:inline-block;
   }

   .Div2{
       border: 4px solid #00FF00;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0 0 0 10px;
       width:120px;
       display:inline-block;
       vertical-align:top;
       height:100px;
   }
   ```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/P6SJq/

Comment: Your answer assumes at least one fixed column width, not sure if that's what he wants.

Comment: Yeah, that is very close to what I want. It seems like both widths must be fixed in this solution. Is there any way not to hard-code the widths of Div1 and Div2?

Comment: Also, IE7 has problems with inline-block, so that may be an issue as well.

Comment: Oh come on, guys, is there a way to do it so that it works on all the web browsers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:table` property like this:

```
.DivParent
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.Div1
{
    border: 4px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:table-cell;
}
.Div2
{
    border: 4px solid #00FF00;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

**Check this** http://jsfiddle.net/XBZad/2/

**EDIT**

**Check This** http://jsfiddle.net/bGvAg/2/

It's work in every browser .

Comment: `display: table` doesn't work in many older browsers, notably IE6 and IE7, and works "oddly" in older versions of Chrome and FF.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the addition about incompatibility with older browsers... What would we do without IE, hah )))

Comment: @ahmd0; Now check my updated example it's work in every broswer

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this source . This will be helpful to you !

```
.DivParent
    {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .Div1
    {
        border: 4px solid #FF0000;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        float:left;
        min-width:300px;
        max-width:900px;
        min-height:100px !important;
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
    }
    .Div2
    {
        border: 4px solid #00FF00;
        width:150px;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Float means.. well, float.  Not fixed.  In order to prevent div2 from moving under one of the divs has to be static, probably the left one.  However, that means you would have to float div2 right (and place it before div1).  The problem would then be that div2 would always be to the right, even when the content of div1 was minimal.

I don't think it's possible to do what you want given only the html you have.  You would have to use some container divs to prevent the wrapping.

Comment: Well, I can easily fix it with the use of <table> but it's all over the web that one should not use tables for positioning.... is it not right?

Comment: @ahmd0 - No, you shouldn't use tables for layout.  I didn't say you can't do what you want, just that you might need to modify the html a bit.  Alternatively, Jasons answer might work if you can live with the the fixed sizes for some elements.